# Nginx location return whole path to proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I have the following config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

location /api{
       proxy_pass http://app:8080/;
    }
}
```

How can I redirect: `http://localhost/api/health` to `http://app:8080/health` with just one location rule? Or do I have to declare a rule for all my backend endpoints?

Comment: Do you want to redirect or do you want to proxy?

Comment: proxy @KshitijJoshi

Comment: You should use `location /api/` instead of `location /api` (add a trailing `/`).